# Error unexpected ;;

Tags: php, laravel

I can´t found my syntax error:

```
$params['title_header'] = '<a href="/product/'.str_slug($article_info->name.'/'.$article_info->article_id.'">'.$article_info->name.'</a> > MODELS';
```

Can you help me to find him?

I´m coding in a laravel controller.php file.

Comment: You are forgetting a parenthesis to close your function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have a close parenthesis after opening `str_slug()` after `article_id`.

```
$params['title_header'] = '<a href="/product/'.str_slug($article_info->name.'/'.$article_info->article_id).'">'.$article_info->name.'</a> > MODELS';
```